# Remove middle initial only if there is one

Tags: excel

[![Image 1][1]][1]

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4X09.png)

I have 1000 rows of data, some have a middle initial... some don't. I need to remove the middle initial so I am left with just first name. When I apply this.... =LEFT(B8,FIND(" ",B8,1)-1) I get an error for those cells that do not have a middle initial or name.

Comment: `=IFERROR(YOUR_FORMULA,"")` is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Your example is confusing. Your two images seem to be from the same worksheet. Your formula refers to A2, but in your example, A2 is blank. Also, in your example, the names are in different columns. Please edit your question to clarify how your data is set up and what you want. It might help to read through the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

With data in column **A**, in another cell enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)) & TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))
```

[image]

The names are a set of words separated by a space.  The formula gets the first word and the last word.